# Fetch constants from API once at the beginning of a Cypress run

Tags: cypress

At the very beginning of my Cypress test run, I want to hit an API endpoint to fetch constants that will be used across my test suite. What's the best way to do this?

Cypress includes a root level `before()` hook (see [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Hooks)). But I'm not sure if I can use it to get what I'm looking for.

I know I can use the `before()` hook per file:

```
let constants;

before(() => {
  cy.request({
    url: "/constants/",
    method: "GET",
  }).then((response) => {
    expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
    constants = response.body;
  });
});

describe("My Tests", () => {
  it("My test", () => {
    console.log(constants.SOME_VALUE);
  });
});
```

But I'd rather do it once, instead of having to repeat the code in every file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't often shown in examples, but it is legit to add properties to the global `cy` object.

So if you want to split that `before()` code out to the `cypress/support/e2e.js` file

```js
before(() => {
  cy.request({
    url: "/constants/",
    method: "GET",
  }).then((response) => {
    expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
    cy.constants = response.body;
  });
})
```

and in the test

```js
describe("My Tests", () => {
  it("My test", () => {
    console.log(cy.constants.SOME_VALUE);
  });
})
```

But the caveats would be

- don't use any property name already used by the Cypress runner (`cy.constants` is currently not used, but maybe it will be in the future)
- be aware of [test isolation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation) rules which try to clear down variables between tests (but won't touch `cy.constants`)
- Typescript will complain since `cy.constants` isn't defined in `cypress.d.ts`, but you can extend the definition.

---

Alternatley, use `Cypress.env()` mechanism if you don't mind the clunky look:

**support**

```js
before(() => {
  cy.request({
    url: "/constants/",
    method: "GET",
  }).then((response) => {
    expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
    Cypress.env('constants', response.body)
  });
})
```

**test**

```js
describe("My Tests", () => {
  it("My test", () => {
    console.log(Cypress.env('constants').SOME_VALUE);
  });
})
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I went with the `cy.constants` approach.